# Best way to store response back into NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

I am a newbie in NetSuite. I am currently consuming a saved search via RESTlet in my C# code, pushing it forward to a wsdl and also receiving a response from the same. Now I want to save the response in NetSuite as well, possibly along with the Transaction list records from which I have created the Saved Search.

Please guide me towards what might be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can always view the repsonse/request in Setup > Integration > SOAP Web Services Usage Log. They are already saved as records, you just need to query them